# Save JS object to Knockout Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, knockout.js

So I'm trying to load JSON from a server via AJAX call. I'm able to map it fine into an array that is being binded in HTML. These objects are saved into an array that is being used as the value for a select tag. If I output to the console what's in the array, all the objects show up fine. But these objects don't show as if they have been preselected in the select box.

What I'm trying to do is have the previous data that a user saved from an old session and continue where they left off without having to redo everything again. So I'm loading all old data and putting it back where it used to be by preselecting the option for them.

Here is the JS I currently have:

```
function BracketsViewModel() {
self.AfcTeams = ko.observableArray([]);

// Normally pulled from server via AJAX with more teams. Hardcoded for simplicity
self.AfcTeams.push(new TeamModel({
    Tricode: "CIN",
    DisplayName: "Bengals"
}));
self.AfcTeams.push(new TeamModel({
    Tricode: "BUF",
    DisplayName: "Bills"
}));
self.AfcTeams.push(new TeamModel({
    Tricode: "DEN",
    DisplayName: "Broncos"
}));
self.AfcTeams.push(new TeamModel({
    Tricode: "CLE",
    DisplayName: "Browns"
}));
self.AfcTeams.push(new TeamModel({
    Tricode: "SD",
    DisplayName: "Chargers"
}));

// Temporary array that holds Team object
self.AfcSelectedWildCards = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    self.AfcSelectedWildCards.push(ko.observable());
}

// Holds selected teams that go to next round
self.AfcDivisionals = ko.computed(function () {
    var tmp = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.AfcSelectedWildCards, function (team) {
        if (team()) {
            tmp.push(team());
        }
    });

    return tmp;
});

// Other properties not shown for simplicity
// This will be loaded from server via AJAX call
var bracketsObject = {
    AfcTeams: [{
        Tri: "CIN",
        Name: "Bengals",
        Rank: "1"
    }, {
        Tri: "HOU",
        Name: "Texans",
        Rank: "2"
    }, {
        Tri: "NE",
        Name: "Patriots",
        Rank: "3"
    }, {
        Tri: "NYJ",
        Name: "Jets",
        Rank: "5"
    }, {
        Tri: "DEN",
        Name: "Broncos",
        Rank: "4"
    }, {
        Tri: "KC",
        Name: "Chiefs",
        Rank: "6"
    }]
};

var afcteams = $.map(bracketsObject.AfcTeams, function (team) {
    return new AltTeamModel(team);
});

// Saving objects to array that is being binded in HTML
for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    self.AfcSelectedWildCards[i] = ko.observable(afcteams[i]);
}
}

function TeamModel(data) {
if (data) {
    this.Tri = data.Tricode;
    this.Name = data.DisplayName;
} else {
    this.Tri = "";
    this.Name = "";
}
this.Rank = ko.observable(0);
}

function AltTeamModel(data) {
    this.Tri = data.Tri;
    this.Name = data.Name;
    this.Rank = ko.observable(data.Rank);
}

ko.applyBindings(new BracketsViewModel());
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Telos8840/q20dm63q/)

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after taking a break from this project, I finally figured out how to bind the objects loaded via AJAX. The problem was that Knockout was binding the document before the AJAX calls were finished so, for whatever reason, the binding wasn't reflecting these changes. What I decided to do was time out the document from applying the binding and load everything from the server first. I then passed in all the objects into the View Model and apply the binding on a half second delay. Everything works great now. Here is the code:

```
function TeamModel(data, isPreData) {
    if (isPreData) {
        this.Tri = data.Tri;
        this.Name = data.Name;
        this.Rank = ko.observable(data.Rank);
    } else {
        if (data) {
            this.Tri = data.Tricode;
            this.Name = data.DisplayName;
        } else {
            this.Tri = "";
            this.Name = "";
        }
        this.Rank = ko.observable(0);
    }
}

var afcteams;
$.getJSON('/Brackets/GetBrackets', { id: someId}, function (bracketsObject) {
    if (bracketsObject) {
        afcteams = $.map(bracketsObject.AfcTeams, function (team) {
            return new TeamModel(team, true);
    });
}
}).fail(function () {
    alert("There was an error getting data from the server.");
});

var teams;
$.getJSON('/Brackets/GetAFCTeams', function (data) {
    teams = $.map(data, function (team) {
        return new TeamModel(team, false);
    });
});

function SetBindings(afcteams, teams) {
    ko.applyBindings(new BracketsViewModel(afcteams, teams));
}

setTimeout(function() {
    SetBindings(afcteams, teams);
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is that you are referencing self, but never declaring it. You need to add `var self = this;` at the top of BracketsViewModel.

The next problem is that AfcTeams is an observable array of TeamModels, but AfcSelectedWildCards is an array of AltTeamModel. They need to be the same view model for options and value to match up.

One way around this is to set optionsValue and value both to 'Tri' as follows:

```
<select class="form-control"
        data-bind="options: AfcTeams,
        optionsText: 'Name',
        optionsCaption: '-- Team --',
        optionsValue: 'Tri',
        value: AfcSelectedWildCards[0]().Tri"></select>
```

Here is a fiddle with these two fixes: http://jsfiddle.net/qpolarbear/8kkamzy7/

Only the Bengals and Broncos are selected because they are the only matching teams between AfcTeams and AfcSelectedWildCards.

Comment: Are you able to create a fiddle that shows the problem? Perhaps returning mock data using [echo](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html#json)?

Comment: Sorry about that, I do declare self but I forgot to put it into the fiddle. I tried doing what you said and it does seem to work fine when the JSON object is hardcoded into the ViewModel. But when I grab it from the server, it won't work. Another issue is that whatever is selected in the first panel should become an option in another panel. This worked previously but doesn't now. I've updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Telos8840/q20dm63q/13/) to reflect this. Here is a working version of selected teams being available for another panel [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Telos8840/tF6Kc/1/)

Comment: Can you give a thorough explanation of the desired user interaction?

The two selects at the top represent wild card teams? Teams selected in the two top selects should appear in the remaining selects?

Comment: So the first two selects and the next panel are both part of the wild card teams. The last panel at the bottom with the '#' in place of the number input will only contain the options that were selected from the wild card teams. I've added the echo as well which is showing the same issue I'm currently experiencing [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Telos8840/q20dm63q/15/)